# Certain routes fail to load their templates on iOS

Tags: angularjs

We've released an Angular 1.6 mobile app onto the app store for Android and Apple devices. Everything appears to work fine on Android devices but on certain Apple devices (i.e. iPhone 5SE) the routing doesn't appear to work.

Here's our routing code:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('login', {
          url: '/login',
          template: '<login></login>',
          params: { newUserRegistered: false },
          resolve : {
            checkAuthTokenAvail : ["$localStorage", "$location", function($localStorage, $location){
              if( typeof $localStorage.AuthToken === "string" && $localStorage.AuthToken.length > 8 ){
                $location.url('/main/dashboard');
              }
            }]
          }
        })
        .state('registration', {
          url: '/registration',
          template: '<registration></registration>'
        })
        .state('password-reset', {
          url: '/password-reset',
          template: '<password-reset></password-reset>'
        })
        .state('main', {
          abstract: true,
          template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
          resolve: {
            checkSession: ["$location", "$localStorage", function($location, $localStorage) {
              if( typeof $localStorage.AuthToken !== "string" ) {
                $location.url('/login');
              }
            }]
          }
        })
        .state('main.dashboard', {
          url: '/main/dashboard',
          template: '<dashboard></dashboard>'
        })
        .state('main.money', {
          url: '/main/money',
          template: '<money></money>'
        })
        .state('main.spending', {
          url: '/main/spending',
          template: '<spending></spending>'
        })
        .state('main.cash', {
          url: '/main/cash',
          template: '<cash></cash>'
        })
        .state('main.snow', {
          url: '/main/snow',
          template: '<snow></snow>'
        });
```

Essentially `money` & `spending` both work fine - we can see the component in the app. But `cash` & `snow` don't. Through debugging we can see that their templates just aren't being loaded whereas the other two are.

I thought that this may have something to do with the version of `angular-ui-router` we are using so I'm branched off and updated to `1.0.0` and changed the routing to use `component` instead of `template` but we still receive the same problem.

I reiterate that this only appears to occur on iOS (iOS 9.0.2 on iPad) devices. Has anyone encountered anything like this? I don't want to have to switch the `templateUrl` to `template` in the component definition as the html itself has grown quite large, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The cause was the use of the exponential operator `**` not being available in the iOS version that we were trying to use.

An additional reason as to why it occurred on load of the screen was to do with the use of a `$scope.$watch` on certain variables which called the function that used the exponential operator. It had nothing to do with how we were routing.